# Practical use case of 'git rm' and 'git mv' with git?

Tags: git, git-rm, git-mv

I know that git provides the 'git rm' and 'git mv' to remove/move files or directories. But, I can't see the practical use case for this.

Normally, I just mv or rm the files or whatever in the command line, and after I'm done with all the necessary actions, I can just run 'git add -u' and 'git add .', as I asked and got answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638897/staging-modified-files-according-to-their-status-with-git).

Am I missing something? Are there any cases that only 'git rm' and 'git mv' capable of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`git mv`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html) and [`git rm`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) are about **updating the index directly**.  While directly moving or deleting files in the working tree won't immediately affect the index.

The [GitFaq](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F) does present `git mv` as:

> just a convenience.  The effect is indistinguishable from removing the file and adding another with different name and the same content.

Answer (score 4):

`git rm` and `git mv` allows you to be more specific/granular about what you're doing.  If you've deleted two directories and want to split up those deletions between two commits, you can use `git rm` to remove only one directory from the staging area, rather than getting them both via `git -u`

Answer (score 1):

you could do it the way you said, but it sounds like it would be simpler to use git rm and git mv as it's a one-step process.