# How can I rename a file, so that git knows I'm renaming it?

Tags: git

When I rename a file, git thinks that I've deleted the file and created another file. How can I rename a file, so that git knows I'm "renaming" it?

Comment: Already asked here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641146/handling-file-renames-in-git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To rename a file with git use `git mv`

```
git mv oldname newname
```

Comment: Down voting for potentially miss leading

Answer (score 4):

`git mv` is just a convinience command as mentioned in [git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F)

> Git has a rename command git mv, but that is just for convenience. The effect is indistinguishable from removing the file and adding another with different name and the same content.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639399/practical-use-case-of-git-rm-and-git-mv-with-git) also tells about the same and some other use cases.

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to traditional SCMs, git track content instead of files,

more detailed description here:
https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F

Comment: This answer isn't really all that clear, it would be better if it had more explanation of how this relates to how Git knows that you've renamed a file.